# In CPython, where does Py_Main get put in scope?

Tags: python, c, implementation, cpython

I have been looking at the CPython source code where `python.h` does the import for most modules. Just by tracing the code, I can't find the point at which the `Py_Main()` routine gets placed into the scope.

I did find the definition for `Py_Main` inside `Modules/main.c`, as well as the prototype in `include/pylifecycle.h`, I just can't seem to piece together where it's getting imported from, or if this is done at the linker level with `make`.

TLDR: 
`#include "python.h"`, `Py_Main` is now in scope... at which point did it get injected there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Py_Main` is declared in [`pylifecycle.h`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.6.3/Include/pylifecycle.h#L54):

```
PyAPI_FUNC(int) Py_Main(int argc, wchar_t **argv);
```

`pylifecycle.h` is included in [`Python.h`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.6.3/Include/Python.h#L116):

```
#include "pylifecycle.h"
```

Whenever you write `#include "Python.h"`, `pylifecycle.h` gets automatically included and you get `Py_Main`.

This was about the function declaration, now what about its code?

**For CPython itself:**

When Python is built, each `.c` file in the [`Python` directory](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.6.3/Python) gets compiled into an object (`.o`) file by the C compiler. Objects files are then [statically linked](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linker_(computing)) together into a standalone executable. On Linux, the usual linker is [GNU ld](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ld).

**For third-party modules:**

For modules that want to use the Python API, the code for `Py_Main` is not included: it is loaded at runtime by the [dynamic linker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_linker).

On Linux (and similarly, on other systems) the compiled Python code is shipped in two ways: as a standalone executable `python`, and as a shared library `python.so`. Both contain the code for `Py_Main` and all the other functions.

Comment: I noticed that. However, the actual definition is in file `Modules/main.c`, which I don't see any references to in the code.

Comment: @SamuelN: If you're wondering how the function gets compiled and linked, that's an entirely different issue from what you asked.

Comment: @user2357112 Yes, that's why I included that in my question `"or if this is done at the linker level with make"`. Thanks for clarifying!

Comment: @user2357112 Just one more question. I am not familiar with how this is done and tried a `grep` for `main.c`, but couldn't find anything. Can you give me some guidance on where to look for where this linking is defined? I tried searching in the `cmake` files, as well as in the `configure` script.

Comment: @SamuelN: it's not clear to me whether you're interested in how the official Python executable is built, or how third-party modules are built. If you clarify that, I can expand my answer

Comment: Andrea, thank you for your answer. This is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @AndreaCorbellini I was looking for how the Python executable is built.